# How to track anchor tags when I create a destination goal in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm new in Google Analytics.  I need to create a goal destination in analytics.

[image]

but my path is: `mydomain.com/#page1`, `mydomain.com/#page2`, how can I set up the destination when I use anchors?

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics does not track the URL fragment by default so you have to update the page path before sending it to Analytics, i.e.:

```
gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID', { 'page_path': location.pathname + location.hash });
```

If you are using use Google Tag Manager you can do it with Built Variables.